# Generate day rows from date range (non consecutive)

Tags: sql, postgresql, between, date-range

I would like to run a query like

```
SELECT distinct( generate_series(timestamp start_date, interval '1' day) as d
FROM NAEDO
WHERE start_date >= '2014/08/13'
AND start_date <= '2014/09/12'
ORDER BY start_date
```

And return data like: (days in range, but from data [ possible non consecutive days ])

```
days
---
13
16
17
18
25
29
1
3
```

Comment: Why not just do:  `select distinct start_date form NAEDO`?

Comment: How do you extract the day?

Comment: extract(day from start_date)

Comment: There is no `generate_series (timestamp, interval)`. A parameter is missing, so it's unclear what you actually want. There might be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT distinct date_trunc('day', start_date) as d
FROM NAEDO
WHERE start_date >= '2014-08-13' AND start_date <= '2014-09-12'
ORDER BY d
```

Comment: But it returns a timestamp. is this postgres standard as-well?

Comment: @mornenel: you probably want `extract(day from start_date)` which returns an integer.

Comment: @mornenel . . . Your original query would extract a date column.  Your sample data has just a day.  If you want day, then a_horse_with_no_name has the right solution.

Comment: Yes. I acknowledged him with a upvote. Hence the inclusion of his snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT start_date, extract(day from start_date) as d
FROM NAEDO
WHERE start_date >= '2014-08-13' AND start_date <= '2014-09-12'
ORDER BY start_date
```

Maybe there is still a way to do it without the extra column...
But this is for a Report and you can just omit the extra column in the report.